# To replace email domain with some different email domain

Tags: regex, webstorm

Trying to replace multiple email domains separated by commas `,` with some different domain e.g.: - 'yopmail.com'.

```
'test1@gmail.com','test2@yahoo.in','test3@something.org','test4@gmail.com','test5@gmail.co.in','test6@gmail.com'
```

So I want a RegEx for my WebStorm IDE to replace those email domain.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Match `@[^']+` (@ followed by as many non-quotes characters as possible, at least one), replace by `@yopmail.com`. Very basic regex use, consider taking a quick regex tutorial

Comment: Thanks Aaron.Yes I will be taking that soon.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a list of those strings

```
import re
a=['test1@gmail.com','test2@yahoo.in','test3@something.org','test4@gmail.com','test5@gmail.co.in','test6@gmail.com']
b=[re.sub(r'@[\w]+','@yopmail',i) for i in a]
#THIS WILL SEARCH AND REPLACE ALPHANUMERIC VALUES AFTER @ WITH YOUR TEXT 
print(b)
```